# open ionic sidemenu from tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to open sidebar menu from tab in ionic2/3 (see the linked image).
i wasn't able to find a solution for it.
there is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386545/open-sidemenu-from-a-tab-button) on ionic1 but not the 2 version

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="page1" tabIcon="someicon"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="page2" tabIcon="someicon"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="page3" tabIcon="someicon"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="page4" tabIcon="someicon"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

i tried to replace component name with a function to navigate from there in my component.ts but it does not work.

```
  tab1Root = page1;
  tab2Root = page2;
  tab3Root = page3;
  tab4Root = this.functionToToggleSidemenu;
  functionToToggleSidemenu(){
    //here i have placed the navigation code
   }
```

[open sidemenu from tab desired output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDgpx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just like you can see in **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/)**:

> Sometimes you may want to call a method instead of navigating to a new
>   page. You can use the `(ionSelect)` event to call a method on your
>   class when the tab is selected.

It'd be something like this:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="openSideMenu()" tabTitle="Sidemenu"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And in the component code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';

Component({...})
export class TabsPage {

  // ...

  constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController) {}

  openSideMenu() {
    this.menuCtrl.open();
  }
}
```

---

Another way to do it would be to add the `menuToggle` directive to the tab button directly, but AFAIK it used to cause some bugs in older versions of Ionic (not really sure if it works properly in the latest versions to be honest). Here you can find the **[MenuToggle docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/MenuToggle/)**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab menuToggle tabTitle="Sidemenu"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```